# Preserving default controller name in url in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

As a I user of FormExtensions.BeginForm() method I've encountered not satisfactory behavior of UrlHelper.GenerateUrl() method.

Having standard routing:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Following method call returns "/"

```
 //Request.RawUrl == "/Home"
 UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
            routeName: null,
            actionName: null,
            controllerName: null,
            routeValues: null,
            routeCollection: RouteTable.Routes,
            requestContext: Request.RequestContext,
            includeImplicitMvcValues: true
         );
```

However, if Home controller is not set as a default in routing, above method call returns "/Home" which is my desired behavior.

Setting method parameters actionName = "Index" and controllerName  = "Home" doesn't help.

What should I do to get url containing controller name? ("/Home")

Comment: Just remove `controller = "Home"` from the defaults

Comment: The point is to use it as a default at the same time

Comment: Then you can always create a new route definition (before the default) with `url: "Home/{action}/{id}",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It works, thank you a lot :) I just added default controller and action. Please post it as an answer if you want. Full route definition: routes.MapRoute(name: "Home", url: "Home/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a additional route definition before the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "Home/{action},
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note that the optional `{id}` segment is not required, because if it were provided, then the controller and action name would be included in the url.